# cp copy command with bash brace expansion

Tags: bash, bash-completion

at the bash prompt I can perform this copy

`cp file.txt test1.txt`

but if I try to copy file.txt to several files like so

```
cp file.txt test{2..4}.txt
```

I get error

> cp: target `test4.txt' is not a directory

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not about bash, it's about cp. If you supply cp with more than two parameters the last one should be a directory to which all others are to be copied.

```
for f in test{2..4}.txt ; do cp file.txt $f ; done
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, you have to understand how *nix shells work.

In the DOS/Windows world, wildcards are handled by the programs. Thus, `xcopy *.txt *.bak`, for instance, means `xcopy` is given 2 parameters: `*.txt` and `*.bak`. How the wildcards are interpreted fully depends on `xcopy`.

In the *nix world, wildcards are handled by the shell. A similar command `xcopy *.txt *.bak`, for instance, gets expanded first becoming `xcopy <list of files ending with .txt> <list of files ending with .back>`. Thus assuming the existence of `file1.txt` to `file4.txt`, plus another file `old.bak`, the command will be expanded to `xcopy file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt old.bak`

For the `cp` command, it's exactly what Michael has written: If you give `cp` more than 2 args, the last arg must be a directory.